# React - Cover page based on route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a simple layout like this:

```
<div id='App'>
    <CoverPage src={this.props.route.cover} />
    {this.props.children}
    <Sidebar />
</div>
```

And react-router configured like this:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route name="home"  path="/" cover="/images/covers/home.jpg" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={HomeRoute} />
    </Route>
    <Route name="register"  path="/register" cover="/images/covers/register.jpg" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={RegisterRoute} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

Is this the correct way to do this? It looks like it renders the whole page again when I go from home to register, but not the other way around (???). I'm too green to understand what's wrong.

(This looks like the most obvious solution if I ever try to implement server-side rendering)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally routing is set up something like this

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={IndexComponent} />
    <Route path="path_one" component={PathOneComponent} />
    <Route path="path_two" component={PathTwoComponent} />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

App is your top level component in which you put this inside your render method, the other components will render inside it.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  /* ... */
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <CoverPage src={this.props.route.cover} />
          {this.props.children}
        <Sidebar />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

http://host/ -> renders IndexComponent inside App

http://host/path_one -> renders PathOneComponent inside App

etc...

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, I get this. But I'm looking for most efficient way to pass parameter from child to parent. This looks promising: http://andrewhfarmer.com/component-communication/
but I'm not sure if it will be a good idea if I ever throw SSR into the mix. Thanks anyway!